# How to change href of Glyphicons and Font Awesome files?

Tags: angular

I developed an app in Angular 4 and used Bootstrap Glyphicons and Font Awesome. Everything was working fine until we deployed the application into a server. The application is accessed through the url `http://hostaddress/applicationame`. The problem I am having is that when I publish the app, the font files of Glyphicons and Font Awesome go to the same directory of all the files generated on `ng build`.

In order to make the application to work, I had to manually edit the `index.html` and change the references to the Angular scripts, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applicationname/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

But since I don't know how or where the Glyphicons and Font Awesome files are referenced, I keep getting the `404` error for those files, because it tries to access

```
http://hostaddress/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
```

instead of

```
http://hostaddress/applicationname/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
```

How to I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Angular-CLI and want to self host a file, you can do this by placing a reference to where the file is via the CLI if you look at .angular-cli.json you will see

```
  },

    "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    ".htaccess",
    "mail.php"
  ],
```

you can see that in the Assets array you can put files anywhere you want,  the default is /src folder   for example I am self hosting my mail.php file, you put it in /src and when you BUILD with the CLI it copies it to the ROOT of your DIST folder

ALSO  make sure you are setting the base href of your site.  it looks like your using "/" as your base href instead of /applicationname/

Comment: Also look at "baseHref (string): Base url for the application being built."
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli